# How To Add Additional Images To A Product In Magento

Tags: php, magento, csv

I can add an image to a product during creating using the following script. However, I'm having trouble loading a product and add additional image to the product media gallery. Do I have to delete the product media gallery and readd all the images at once? It's one image per row in a csv file.

```
public function addImage($product, $image)
{
    $imagePath = $this->downloadImage($image);
    $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()));
    if (is_file($imagePath)) {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a script to add images? Adding images in magento can be easily done via the admin interface.

Just login to the admin panel, Catalog > Manage Products > Edit Product > Images (on left panel).

Answer (score 0):

You add the additional images using the following script.

```
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
// additional images
    if ($import_product[29] != '') {
        $addImages = explode(",", trim($import_product[29]));
        foreach ($addImages as $additional_image) {
            $image_directory = $dir .DS.'data'.DS. trim($additional_image);
            if (file_exists($image_directory)) {
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
            } else {
                $image_directory = $dir . 'data' . DS . 'comingsoon.jpg';
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
            }
        }
        echo 'Additional images for product ' . $product->getName() . ' ' . $product->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

The **$import_product[29]** is an array of images separated by commas.  Please refer my tutorial as well which explains how to set default image as well.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-add-main-image-and-additional-image-to-the-products-pro-grammatically-magento/